# How to write tkinter entries in text file?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a Tk(root) window with one entry and a button and I have created two loops under a button which takes the value from the entry of Tk(root) window and generates the matrix entries in x and y direction (matrix form) in a different Tk(top) window. Now, I want to write all the entries (from matrix of entries) to text file. Since the number of matrix entries changes based on the value we put in entry of Tk(root) window, I want to copy all the entries in text file.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font

root=Tk()
root.state('zoomed')

bold20= font.Font(family='Times', size=18)
bold15= font.Font(family='Times', size=15)
bold30= font.Font(family='Times', size=30, weight='bold')
boldunderline30= font.Font(family='Times', size=30, weight='bold', underline=True)

topFrame = Frame(root, width=10000, height=500, relief= "raised", borderwidth=3)
topFrame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

label15= Label(topFrame, text="Enter the matrix range:", font=bold20)
label15.grid(row=8, column=3, padx=200, pady=10, sticky=W)
entry1=Entry(topFrame)
entry1.grid(row=8, column=3, padx=600, pady=10, sticky=W)

def matrix_size():
    top= Tk()       
    for x in range (1, int(entry1.get())+1):
        for y in range(1,int(entry1.get())+1):
            entry = Entry(top)
            entry.grid(row= x, column= y, sticky= 'we', pady= 2)
    def save():
        with open('C:\Fourth Term @ Dal\Project\Collaboration\Sensitivity analysis\GUI\Operating Characteristics\ABC.txt', 'w') as f:        
                f.write(entry.get())
                f.close()

    savebutton = Button(top, borderwidth=2, bg="skyblue", text="Save info.", font=bold15, width=7, command=save)
    savebutton.grid(row=int(entry1.get())+3, column=4, sticky=N)
    top.mainloop()
enterdata= Button(topFrame, bg="skyblue", text="Enter", font=bold20, command=matrix_size)
enterdata.grid(row=8, column=3, padx=750, pady=20, sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

If I run the above code and click on the save button after entering something in the matrix of entries, it copies only last entry in the text file but I want to copy all the entries. It would be great, if someone can help me figuring out the issue. TIA

Comment: Can you paste your code here instead of attaching the image? It helps with understanding and debugging.

Comment: Yeah, I have added the code, thanks

Comment: You're only calling `.get()` on a single entry widget.

Comment: yeah I know because the number of entries are not fixed and it changes every time you change the main entry value.

Comment: Hey folks, it would be great if someone could help me solve this problem. Thanks :)